# Dynamic file name for Bulk Insert Task in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I am using bulk insert task in SSIS to transfer Csv file to database table. it is perfectly working fine for fixed file name. But I need to source file name be passed via my  .net application.

Below is the screenshot of the same. Now I am getting with complication error package "connection element is not found" error showing.

[image]

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DestinationConnection` property is for the connection to where the data will be loaded and `BatchSize` specifies how many rows are in each batch.  To use a parameter for the source file name, add the parameter (or variable) as the expression for the `ConnectionString` property of the Flat File Connection Manager that's being used.  This can be found by clicking the ellipsis on the Expressions field of the Properties window for the connection manager and selecting the `ConnectionString` property.